# How can i get input text from an entrybox in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So i am trying to get an text input for my program but tkinter doesn't seem to register it,
and i don't know what i have done wrong

```
    window = self.newWindow(value)

    label = tk.Label(window, text="Intfix to Postfix Convert")
    label.place(x=0, y=20)

    e1 = tk.Entry(window)
    text = e1.get()
    e1.place(x=0, y=50)

    rezultat = tk.Text(window, width=20, height=3)
    rezultat.place(x=0, y=80)

    button = tk.Button(window, text="Enter")
    button.place(x=127, y=46)
    button.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.passValue(rezultat, text))
```

My code looks something like this. Everything else is working the `self.newWindow(value)` is just
a function that creates a new window from the main one

so i said `text=e1.get()` but i ran the debbuger and it says it is an empty string and i want to pass this text through the function `passValue()`(a function that passes the value to the controller), i used `button.bind()` to do that. Is that ok?

I tested it by putting a default value at text like `text="My name"` and it did pass the value so that should be in order but i don't know why doesn't it get it from the entry box like it should.

I even tried to do `e1.insert(0,"some random thing")` and `text= e1.get()` and it did get it so i think there's a problem with the input.

Do i need to use some special kind of input function?

The whole code:

```
class Gui:

    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.main = tk.Tk()
        self.main.title("DSA Quiz Helper")
        self.__controller = controller

    def IntFixPostExecute(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        selection = widget.curselection()
        value = widget.get(selection[0])
        self.IntfixPostfixWindow(value)

    def mainWindow(self):
        self.main.geometry("800x500")

        # to do scrollbar
        lb = tk.Listbox(self.main, width=50, height=30)
        lb.insert(1, "Intfix and Postfix Calculator")
        lb.insert(2, "Something else")
        lb.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.IntFixPostExecute)
        lb.pack()

    def IntfixPostfixWindow(self, value):
        window = self.newWindow(value)

        label = tk.Label(window, text="Intfix to Postfix Convert")
        label.place(x=0, y=20)

        e1 = tk.Entry(window)
        text = e1.get()
        e1.place(x=0, y=50)

        rezultat = tk.Text(window, width=20, height=3)
        rezultat.place(x=0, y=80)

        button = tk.Button(window, text="Enter")
        button.place(x=127, y=46)
        button.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.passValue(rezultat, text))
        print(text)

    def passValue(self, rezultat, value):
        returnValue = self.__controller.InfixToPostC(rezultat, value)
        rezultat.insert(tk.INSERT, returnValue)

    def newWindow(self, msg):
        newwind = tk.Toplevel(self.main)
        q1 = tk.Frame(newwind)
        q1.pack()
        newwind.geometry("500x230")
        return newwind

    def run(self):
        self.mainWindow()
        self.main.mainloop()
```

if i set this manually it works. I don't understand why i doesn't work from entrybox input

```
    text = tk.StringVar()
    e1 = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=text)
    text.set("x+y*2")
    text = e1.get()
    e1.place(x=0, y=50)
```

I think i figured it out (correct me if i am wrong). I think there is a problem
with the button because as soon as a newwindow is open, the button automatically clicks itself, when at first in the entry box there is no text written yet(so it sends to the controller with the initial text(which is empty)). The problem is why the button auto-clicks itself( or anyway auto-runs the function `passValue`) and why after i input the text and click the button again it does nothing(so as i understand it works only one time and auto-runs itself, at first there is no text in entrybox and the button auto-runs itself,therefore passing an empty string

Comment: I can post the whole gui class if you don't understand what is going on from this code snippet

Comment: post your whole code. Dont know where it get lost yet

Comment: hmmm, have u tried using argument `textvariable` to e1?

Comment: I posted the gui class, i can also post the controller part but i don't really think is relevant because after running the debbuger it showed that text was empty from the start, so it just sended an empty string to the controller

Comment: @CoolCloud, something like this:  `entry(window, textvariable=text)` . I tried before but i am going to try again maybe it works. Should i declare text as `tk.StringVar` or  leave it like a normal string?

Comment: as far as ik you shud define a variable bfre using it in tkinter, so mayb it depends on ur need, if it is `StringVar()` or `IntVar()`

Comment: @TiagoOliveira, I think you are right, i wil modify and try to see  if it works.Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TiagoOliveira, yess it finally works thanks a lot `button = tk.Button(window, text="Enter", command=lambda: self.passValue(rezultat, e1.get()))` This is what i changed

Comment: I just copied what i wrote to an answer so other people don't think this is still active :D

Answer (score 1):

You should use entryname.get() to get the text that is inside that entry instead of declaring stringVar() and making that much more unreadable and hard to comprehend and to work with. But this is my point of view! – Tiago Oliveira 48 mins ago
I think what is happening is that u use the method right after declaring the entry widget wich means u are going to get a "" empty string because that's nothing that was written there, u need to replace on the command parameter with entryname.get() instead of declaring variable = entryname.get() and passing that as parameter wich will always be empty! Hope this helps!